# How to extract a named parameter from url?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish, ejb

I am new to the Java EE environment. I was wondering how can we extract a named parameter from a request url in servlets.

For instance I have an url pattern `products/show/:id`. How can I extract the value of `id` from the requested url?

After doing a bit of research on Google, I learned about the `@PathParam` annotation. However it seems it only works with RESTful webapps. I need something generic or cut out for simple servlets.

Comment: If you're using basic servlets, I think you will need to parse the result of [`HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

String pathWithValue = request.getPathInfo();
String value = pathWithValue.subString(pathWithValue.indexOf("products/show/".length())

getPathInfo is automatically URL decoded and does not contains the query string too!
Consider that getPathInfo value depends on the servlet mapping configuration in web.xml: f.e. /*

Answer (score 0):

If you have an HTTPServletRequest object to deal with, try putting this in your code:

```
Enumeration<String> e = request.getParameterNames();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    String param = e.nextElement();
    System.out.println(param + ": " + request.getParameter(param));
}
```

That will go through all the available forms or objects that you can get the value of using request.getParameter(id) (which will change depending on what buttons are clicked, fields are active, etc.).